# qsort() doesn't sort data from structure

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I've got a structure:

```
typedef struct personalData
{
    char name[20];
    char * remarks;
    int age;
    float weight;
} personalData;
```

I need to sort data by weight using `qsort()`. Here's my `weightSort` function:

```
void weightSort(personalData * data[], int len)
{
    qsort(data, len, sizeof(struct personalData *), structSortWeight);
}
```

where `len` = 10(calculated before using some different functions, but it probably doesn't matter), `data[]` is defined in `main()`:

```
struct personalData * data[10];
```

and finally `structSortWeight`:

```
int structSortWeight(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    personalData *p1 = (personalData *)a;
    personalData *p2 = (personalData *)b;

    return (p1->weight - p2->weight);
}
```

My program crashes when it starts sorting. I want to add that when I change the third argument in `qsort()` to `sizeof(float)` it doesn't crash but `p1->weight` and `p2->weight` point to some rubbish.

The calling function in `main()`:

```
weightSort(data, len);
```

`personalData * data[]` has some data already assigned.

Comment: And if the problem is what the fragments you've presented so far suggest it might be, then you need to pay attention to your compiler's warnings, and to turn them on if you're not getting any.

Comment: It is not legal to pass `struct personalData * data[10];` as first parameter of `weightSort`. The types are not compatible. How did you manage to pull this off? What does your calling code look like?

Comment: I'm getting no errors at the moment as I've changed some things, thanks to the answers, and the program doesn't crash but still pointers point to some rubbish. I'll change the code in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison function receives pointers to two elements of the list, each of which is also a pointer.  So the real type of each parameter is `personalData **`, but you cast them to `personalData *`.  So you're treating a pointer as a structure instance, which is why you're seeing garbage.

You need to add an additional level of indirection in your comparison function:

```
int structSortWeight(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    // no need to cast from void *
    const personalData **p1 = a;
    const personalData **p2 = b;

    return ((*p1)->weight - (*p2)->weight);
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: `(*p1)->weight - (*p2)->weight` is a bad compare for `float`.  The subtraction may result in 0.5 (or any non-zero magnitude less than 1), which when converted to an `int` is 0 - incorrectly implying the weights are the same.  Code also is a problem when the difference is well outside the `int` range.

Answer (score 7):

This array declaration:

> ```
> struct personalData * data[10];
> ```

does not declare an object suitable for use as the first parameter to

> ```
> void weightSort(personalData data[], int len)
> ```

The variable and function parameter have different levels of indirection.  Your actual data is an array of *pointers to* `struct personalData`, whereas the function parameter is appropriate for an array of the structures themselves.  This produces undefined behavior.  Probably more functionally relevant, the item size that you pass to `qsort()` is therefore incorrect: with the data as declared in `main()`, you want as item size not the size of `struct personalData`, but rather the size of a pointer to one (`sizeof(struct personalData *)`).

Furthermore, your comparison function is wrong.  In the first place, it must return an `int`, not a `float`, but in the second place, since the elements you are sorting are pointers to structures, the arguments presented to the comparison function will be pointers to such pointers.  You treat them instead as pointers directly to structures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought the declaration isn't suitable for these objects. However, I was given it and supposed to use that declaration but in my opinion it was a mistake. I've changed your suggestions in my code but p1->weight and p2->weight still point to nothing sensible. As a result, qsort() doesn't sort the data. I've put these changes in the code in the question.

Comment: @botq, you did not address one of the key issues I pointed out in my answer: "since the elements you are sorting are pointers to structures, the arguments presented to the comparison function will be pointers to such pointers. You treat them instead as pointers directly to structures."  Thus, *of course* `p1->weight` and `p2->weight` do not point to anything sensible.  No matter how you cast them, these pointers point to other pointers, not to objects of type `personalData`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature for the [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) comparison function is

```
int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)
```

Returning a `float` does not work at all.

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't fix the problem. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

`return (p1->weight - p2->weight);` is not a suitable compare. This subtracts 2 `float` values and converts to `int`.   The compare function must return the sensible consistent results.

Consider weights A,B,C: 1.1, 2.0, 2.9.

Comparing f(A,B) returns `int` 0.
Comparing f(B,C) returns `int` 0.
Comparing f(A,C) returns `int` 1.  // This does not make sense if A==B and B==C

This inconsistency can fool `qsort()` resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).

A better compare function

```
int structSortWeight2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const personalData **p1 = (const personalData **)a;
    const personalData **p2 = (const personalData **)b;
    // 2 compares are done, each returning an `int`
    return ((*p1)->weight > (*p2)->weight) - ((*p1)->weight < (*p2)->weight);
}
```

Code has other issues as detailed in [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066733/2410359)

Comment: Very useful advice. That fixed my next problem as some close weights wasn't sorted by qsort(). Thank you.